# How to Configure Gerrit for Git over HTTP

Tags: git, gerrit

I've setup Gerrit on Ubuntu Server 14.04. Everything seems to be running correctly and I have users using LDAP to authenticate to the web interface and we've been pulling and pushing commits. I'm not using a reverse proxy in Apache to get to port 8080 but just created a redirect in iptables from 80 to 8080 (probably not the best but since I was having config issues with Apache after setting up phpmyadmin it was what I got to work).

I, along with a good number of my developers, have no problem with using the SSH protocol to fetch/pull and push to the remote. However, there are some holdouts who can't quite grasp the whole process of PuTTY, SSH, and Git from a Windows client. Since they're hung up on this aspect and their major complaint is around lack of SSH support from libgit2 in Visual Studio I wanted to give them the ability to use HTTP instead.

For the life of me I cannot figure out why we cannot connect over HTTP. I've tried the following URIs:

- http://username@gerrit.example.com:29418/p/Project
- http://username@gerrit.example.com/p/Project
- http://gerrit.example.com/p/Project
- Probably other combinations...

I get an error about not being about to read refs/info (or something like that).

Ideally I would like to have the users be able to use their network auth *(ActiveDirectory or NTLM, whatever works)*, but I could be just as fine as having them use a generated password.

Do I need to setup Apache as a reverse proxy to get this to work? That was my thought. Basically have Apache perform some kind of authentication *(LDAP or NTLM, this'll be another question)*? Can I setup Apache to do NTLM auth and pass that through on a reverse proxy setup?

I can't seem to find any information except that it is possible to have HTTP for push and pull.

Halp, please?!